# Calculate number of strokes to colour a 2d array Canvas

Tags: java, arrays

Today I had one interview coding test. Where I need to create 2d painting array canvas. Where all adjacent cells needs to be coloured with similar colour, after colouring get number of colours used to paint whole canvas.

Here is image for reference.

```
https://pasteboard.co/ITA9nFL.png
```

And here is my code, where I could not traverse the 2d array and find out the solution.

```
package Test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inp = in.nextInt();
        int arraySize = inp - 1;
        String[][] canvas = new String[arraySize][arraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++) {

            String inpString = in.next();
            if (inpString.length() == inp - 1) {

                char[] ch = new char[inpString.length()];

                for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) {

                    canvas[i][j] = Character.toString(ch[j]);

                }
            }

        }

        String[][] tempcanvas = canvas;

        for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < inp; j++) {

            }

        }

    }

}
```

May I know please what could have been done after where I have left my code ? I literally could not think ahead how to do this further. Got confused to keep track of adjacent cells etc and lost.

Can anyone help on this how to solve this problem ...?

Comment: the category for this problem is called flood fill which can be implemented easily using DFS/BFS

Comment: @Mox, thanks for the hint, It helped..!